# Netbeans 8.1 on Debian 9 no plugins available

Tags: netbeans, debian

I've just installed Debian 9 and NetBeans 8.1. I use to work with this setup so I'm familiarized with it. But now, my NetBeans is not detecting any 'available plugins' (it just come with the basics, but I need PHP support, in addition to typescript and more stuff).

- I have a working Internet connection
- In 'settings' -> 'proxy settings', 'use system proxy settings' is checked, furthermore when I click on 'Test connection' it shows the green check.
- At '~/.netbeans/8.1/var/log/.log' it looks like there is no error showing.
- I have ran NetBeans with root privileges and same happens.
- Something strange is that, when I click 'Check for newest', it "checks" so quick (double quote because I doubt it does anything).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans 7 hides most plugins by default.

From Tools (Menu) -> Plugins (Menu) -> Settings (Tab) 
Certified Plugins - http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0.1/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz

Plugin Portal - http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/7.0/catalog.xml.gz
and NetBeans Distribution

and make sure each of them is checked. If these are not present or not checked, you will not see anything in the list of Available Plugins (tab). Make sure you Reload Catalog on the Available Plugins tab after adding these.

Comment: Lol, you are right. Even I'm running 8.1 and you talked about 7, the solution is the very same. It looks like I had to activate the Configuration of Update Centers. I can't understand why this comes deactivated by default. Anyway thank you very much.